# How do I get my VBA Code to loop through all sheets in workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following code to remove classifications I do not require in my tables:

```
Sub RemoveOldPlatforms()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")

    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Coniferous", "Broafleaf", "Mixedwood", "Water", "Exposed Land / Barren", "Urban / Developed", "Greenhouses", "Shrubland", "Wetland", "Grassland"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ws.Range("$A$2:$J$100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

As is, I am specifying a single identified worksheet, but how do I loop it through all worksheets in my workbook (20+)?

Comment: `For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Review the questions under "Related" on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi pretty simple code to check every worksheets in a workbook,

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'called once per worsheet
Next ws
```

Here I loop trough all the worksheet to find all tables availiable in ANOTHER workbook and display it inside a ComboBox

```
Private Sub UpdateTablesFromFile()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim text As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim FileToOpen As String

FolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & ComboBox1.Value 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath

For Each ws In Workbooks(ComboBox1.Value).Worksheets
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects

        text = ws.Name & "\" & tbl.Name
        ImportForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem text 'add every tables in my entire workbook inside the ComboBox2

    Next tbl
Next ws

Workbooks(ComboBox1.Value).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
Sub EnteringAllSheetsOneByOne()
    For Each ws In Excel.Workbooks("YourWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets
        ws.Select
        Call RemoveOldPlatforms(ws) 'must to be called here and use ws as parameter
    Next ws
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub

' Just add the "ws" parameter to your current sub
Sub RemoveOldPlatforms(ws As Object)
   'Dim ws As Worksheet

   'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")

    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Coniferous", "Broafleaf", "Mixedwood", "Water", "Exposed Land / Barren", "Urban / Developed", "Greenhouses", "Shrubland", "Wetland", "Grassland"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ws.Range("$A$2:$J$100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

**Note:** Please pay atention to all I've commented, `Dim` and `Set` in this case are not necessary